# Recursive PHP function returns an array result

Tags: php

I have a problem understanding recursive functions in PHP.

I'd like to retrieve all services that renew an old service, starting from an old ID (Service). Returning an array result.

For example, my table SERVICES

```
ID  | Name  | DateExpire  |IDOldServiceRenewed|
-----------------------------------------------
1   | Serv1 | 2018-10-10  |                   |
-----------------------------------------------
2   | Serv2 | 2018-10-11  |                   |
-----------------------------------------------
3   | Serv3 | 2018-10-12  |         2         |
-----------------------------------------------
4   | Serv4 | 2018-10-13  |         3         |
-----------------------------------------------
5   | Serv5 | 2018-10-14  |         1         |
-----------------------------------------------
6   | Serv6 | 2018-10-15  |                   |
-----------------------------------------------
7   | Serv7 | 2019-02-10  |         4         |
-----------------------------------------------
8   | Serv8 | 2019-05-15  |         5         |
-----------------------------------------------
```

So in my example, if I want to know all new services (in order to renew from older to newer) of old service with `ID = 2` I'd like to return an array like this:

```
$result = array(
  "0" => array(
    "ID" => 3,
    "Expired" => 2018-10-12
  ),
  "1" => array(
    "ID" => 4,
    "Expired" => 2018-10-13
  ),
  "2" => array(
    "ID" => 7,
    "Expired" => 2019-02-10
  )
)
```

For `ID = 1`:

```
$result = array(
  "0" => array(
    "ID" => 5,
    "Expired" => 2018-10-14
  ),
  "1" => array(
    "ID" => 8,
    "Expired" => 2019-05-15
  )
)
```

I tried starting with a function like this, but I always get NULL in var_dump:

```
function get_recursive_id_services($idOldService, &$result) {

    $sql = "SELECT SERVICES.* FROM SERVICES WHERE IDOldServiceRenewed = ?";

    $s = $db->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute(array($idOldService));
    $ris = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($ris) {

        $id = $ris['ID'];
        $result[$idOldService] = $id;
        $result[] = get_recursive_id_services($id, $result);

    } else {

        return $result;
    }
}

// Test

$temp = array();
$result = get_recursive_id_services(2, $temp);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Please [read this](https://www.elated.com/articles/php-recursive-functions/) to understand recursion. Thanks.

Comment: Why don_'t you return anything in case `$ris` evaluates to something?

Comment: Hi, i've already found this article but all examples print result. I need to update an array $result to use outside the funcion

Comment: You want your result array to contain sub-arrays, yet you are pushing a scalar value onto it here, `$result[$idOldService] = $id;` - I don’t think that makes sense. And passing `&$result` by reference should not be necessary here either, I think. The function does not need to ability to modify the array _outside_ of its own scope, because it the current state of the array is returned at the end of each recursion step.

Answer (score 3):

There is one major problem with your code. Your function takes `$result` parameter as a reference. It means that this line:

```
$result[] = get_recursive_id_services($id, $result);
```

will give something like this:

```
array(
    1 => array( "id" => ... , "expired" => ...),
    2 => array( 1 => array( "id" => ... , "expired" => ...) )
)
```

Instead you want this:

```
return get_recursive_id_services($id, $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working thanks to [Karol Samborski's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54362894/63550).

```
function get_recursive_id_services($id, &$result) {

  $sql = "SELECT SERVICES.* FROM SERVICES WHERE IDOldServiceRenewed = ?";
  $s = $db->prepare($sql);
  $s->execute(array($id));
  $ris = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($ris) {
    $idNewService = $ris['ID'];
    $result[] = array("ID" => $idNewService, "DateExpire" => $ris['DateExpire']);
    return get_recursive_id_services($idNewService, $result);
  }
  else {
    return $result;
  }

}
```